# Prove Newtons trident is an algebraic curve

Tags: geometry, algebraic-geometry, curves, projective-geometry, algebraic-curves

I was working on a problem where I have two curves $C_1 \longleftrightarrow x^2-y=0$ and $C_2 \longleftrightarrow xy-1=0$ in $\mathbb{A}^2$ (so a parabola and a hyperbola). Now consider the connection lines from a point of $C_1$ to a point of $C_2$ parallel to the y-axis. Then I have to show that the points lying on the middle of these lines form an algebraic curve. The problem also says that this curve is called Newtons trident.

I made a sketch so I could see how the curve lies inbetween $C_1$ and $C_2$. The left side of the y-axis is trivial, since it follows both asymptotes. For the right side I am a little confused. Because how i look at is my new curve (let's call it $C$) has to go through the intersection of $C_1$ and $C_2$. But if I look up Newtons trident, it does not go through this intersection. Why is that the case?

My second question is how can I find the formule for this algebraic curve. I suppose I can take x fixed and then look at the middle of both y-values. But I would need absolute value for that, right? So I have no idea how to do this. Or should I first go to $ \mathbb{C}P^2$, then I get
$$ f_1(x_0,x_1,x_2)=x_1^2-x_0x_2$$
$$ f_2(x_0,x_1,x_2)=x_1x_2-x_0^2$$
Could someone please help me? Thanks in advance!

Comment: For the first question, I looked up a trident here: https://mathshistory.st-andrews.ac.uk/Curves/Trident/
From my sketch, this is just a reflected version (w.r.t. $y$-axis) of the curve you should get for this question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the easiest way to find an equation of the curve in this case is by parametrizing it.

We parametrize the parabola by $(t, t^2)$ and hyperbola by $(t,1/t)$. So the midpoints are parametrized by
$$(t, \frac{t^2 + 1/t}{2}) = (t, \frac{t^3 + 1}{2t})$$
and it can be readily seen that the equation for these points is
$$2xy = x^3 + 1$$
In general, you could compute the resultant to work out the equation of parametrized curve, see [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1612811/are-all-rationally-parametrized-plane-curves-algebraic-how-does-one-find-their) question for example.

The algebraic curve $2xy = x^3 + 1$ is a particular case of trident curve (which in general have the form $xy+ax^{3}+bx^{2}+cx=d$, according to [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trident_curve))

Comment: Thank you! I still have a question. You can see that $(1,1)$ is a point on $C_1$ and on $C_2$. So then the middle of the connection lines between those two points, is just the point $(1,1)$ itself, right? But I see in your formula (and in the graph you cited in your other remark) that $C$ does not contain $(1,1)$, how can this be the case? I would think $C$ would intersect both curves in the point $(1,1)$.

Comment: Also is it possible to solve this question without using a parametrization? I can see the parametrization does make it easier.

Comment: @Oopsilon, the equation $2xy = x^3 +1$ certainly contains the point $(1,1)$ which, as you correctly mentioned, is the intersection of $C_1$ and $C_2$. As I said, the graph I cited doesn't contain this point, because it is "reflected" about the $y$ axis. And if you look at the general equation, the reflection about the $y$ axis, i.e. $x \mapsto -x$ preserves this general form.